# Triggered abilities from multiple players. Whose resolves first?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If triggered abilities from sources controlled by multiple players all trigger at the same time, in what order do they resolve?

For example, if I control [Obzedat, Ghost Council](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Obzedat%2C%20Ghost%20Council) and at least two other creatures on my side of the field and my opponent plays [Archfiend of Depravity](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Archfiend%20of%20Depravity), can I use Obezdat's ability of exiling him to save him from Archfiend's ability at the end step? Since both abilities trigger at the beginning of the end step, whose ability resolves first?

Comment: Whilst I understand the question, Archfiend gives you free choice over which creatures get sacrificed, so why do you need to do anything to rescue Obzedat other than choose two other creatures? Do you intend to choose Obzedat, then also exile it and only end up sacrificing one creature?

Comment: @doppelgreener Archfiend says sacrifice all BUT 2 creatures, not sacrifice 2 creatures.

Comment: Oh, that's true, I misread. So this is a plan to make Obzedat exempt during the choosing and sacrificing part, then have Obzedat return so that you have 3 creatures? (Just trying to understand what's being attempted here, since you could _still_ just choose for Obzedat to stay alive easily enough, so nothing tricky needs to be done to 'save' it.)

Comment: This is kind of a duplicate of [What order do triggered abilities happen in if multiple things trigger at the same time?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/7355/what-order-do-triggered-abilities-happen-in-if-multiple-things-trigger-at-the-sa) - that question gives a different example, but the relevant rules are the same.

Comment: While the other question is newer, the answers are more general since this specific trigger set is an end of turn, and can only happen at a specific point in the timing of the game, where death triggers can happen on any player's turn and need a more general answer. I am voting to close this as a duplicate of the more generally applicable answer.

Answer (score 12):

Triggers controlled by your opponent will resolve first, so you cannot use Obzedat's ability to exile it before the Archfiend's ability resolves. [Rule 603.3b](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Triggered_ability) says

> If multiple abilities have triggered since the last time a player received priority, **each player, in APNAP order, puts triggered abilities he or she controls on the stack in any order he or she chooses**. (See rule 101.4.) Then the game once again checks for and resolves state-based actions until none are performed, then abilities that triggered during this process go on the stack. This process repeats until no new state-based actions are performed and no abilities trigger. Then the appropriate player gets priority.

["APNAP"](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Magic_Golden_Rules) here means **Active Player, Non-Active Player**. When the abilities trigger, first the active player (the player taking the turn) puts abilities they control on the stack, then the other player does. This means that your Obzedat's ability goes on the stack, followed by the Archfiend's ability, so the Archfiend's ability resolves before you have a chance to exile Obzedat.